# Best way to set environment variables in NetBeans Platform App

Tags: netbeans, environment-variables, netbeans-platform

I would like to set some environment variables for a NetBeans Platform app. Is there a clean way of doing this so the environment variables are set when I start the app without having to write a custom startup script? I'm doing this on a linux environment.

https://netbeans.org/features/platform/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass `arguments/commandline` parameters to the NetBeans Platform app during startup, you can pass those parameters either directly to the launcher or via the `etc/<brandingname>.conf` file which is located in the distribution of the application. There you can determine any options via the default_options attribute. Example-

`default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/user"
default_cachedir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/cache"
default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-ea --branding mybrandingcluster"
jdkhome="jre"`

Furthermore, you can separately assign the path of the Java
Platform, the user directory, and additional clusters in this file.

If you are looking forward to save `environment variables` specific to your application you can use the [NbPreferences](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/NbPreferences.html%20%20NbPreferences%20API) API. Detailed example is listed [in Geertjan´s blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/preferences_api_and_netbeans_ide)